# Add 2fa to front end login EE2

Tags: ee2, login

I have an EE2 site with a front end user login for front end 'admin' users and I need to add 2fa to this, there are no plugins available that offer this functionality, they only either; deal with the CP login, or are for a different version of EE.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend considering upgrading this CMS install before investing in what it would take to add 2FA to an EE2 installation. It will take a decent amount of developer time to create an add-on package that integrates with a third-party 2FA service, and then you'd have to own this add-on for future upgrades of the CMS.

I recommend upgrading, and then considering new add-on development or purchasing of an add-on that handles 2FA. Brewing your own add-on for EE2 would be ludicrous at this point.

Comment: HI, thank you, we have considered upgrading but it's not an option unfortunately.